# Set-up GRASS for use in QGIS 3.10 with Mac OS X

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, installation

I want to use GRASS 7.6 with QGIS 3.10 installed on my Mac (10.13 - High Sierra).

I have installed QGIS 3.10 for Mac via this link : https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html
I have installed GRASS 7.6 for Mac via this link : http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads

QGIS and GRASS both work separately, however when I am unable to use GRASS via QGIS. After activating the plugin in QGIS, I do not have access to any of the features (New Mapset, Open Mapset, etc.). Accessing at **Plugins > GRASS > GRASS Options > General**, I get the following error message :

```
Currently selected GRASS installation is not valid
```

[image]

I have the application located in my Applications directory.

[image]

What are the steps that I should do to be able to use GRASS via QGIS?

Comment: Try `/Applications/GRASS-7.6.app/Contents/MacOS/Grass`

Answer (score 1):

They announced in the QGIS github (see issue : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34721#issuecomment-592090316) that the plugin was abandoned and that GRASS should be used directly via **Processing > Toolbox > GRASS**